# Update Iteration Capacity without Project Administator Role

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In our company, only users with a Project Amin role can update the Iteration Capacity in TFS.  Is there a setting we can add to a Contributor role to allow each individual to update their own Capacity for a given Iteration?  We do not want to give everyone Admin role as they can change everything on the site, but need every individual to go update their own capacity and add their vacation days ahead of the sprint planning session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually users in your team **do not need full Project Admin role** to update Iteration Capacity.

You could simply follow below  prerequisites:

> - You must connect to a team project. If you don't have a team project    yet, create one in TFS/VSTS.
> - You must **be a member of the Contributors group** or be **granted    Stakeholder access to add or modify work items**. Or, you must have
>     your View work items in this node, and your Edit work items in this
>     node permissions set to Allow.
> - If you haven't been added to a team project or team, get added now.

As you can see, you just need to assign the users in contributors group or modify work item in this node permission to **allow**. More details please take a look at this tutorial--  [Set your team's capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scrum/set-capacity?view=vsts&tabs=vertical), the same for Iteration.